# Having a model to relate to several different models

Tags: python, django

I have a simple notification model:

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
    model = '''What to put here?'''
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)
```

I need the notification to relate to several different models, for example; posts, user follows, etc

Is there anyway in django you can relate to several models instead of creating a notification model for each one?

I want to avoid models like this:
PostLikeNotification, UserFollowNotification, etc.

So does django have this functionality? I couldn't find it anywhere in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Content Types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/)/[Generic Relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations)

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=None, null=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, default=None, null=True)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def model_object(self):
        content_type = self.content_type
        object_id = self.object_id
        if content_type is not None and object_id is not None:
            MyClass = content_type.model_class()
            model_object = MyClass.objects.filter(pk=object_id)
            if model_object.exists():
                return model_object.first()
        return None
```

Here we are storing the Model ([Using the Content Types framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/)) and Primary Key (must be an Integer in this example) of the related object in the Notification model, then adding a property method to fetch the related object.

With this you can relate your notifications to any other model.  You could also use the [`ForeignKey.limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) argument on the `content_type` field to validate that it only accepts certain models.

Answer (score 0):

Django need to know the model before creating a relation, you can store the model in char field like `post:23` `user_follow:41` and define a `get_model` method that will parse that field and return the right model object

Answer (score 0):

All depends on your design, you have several options.  Different options depend on the size of your database:

- How many notifications are there?
- Do you need to update the notifications often?
- Or most of the notifications are inserted once and then read often?

---

#### Use an abstract model

Use an abstract model and actually create the `PostLikeNotification` and `UserFollowNotification` and other models of such a kind.

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    # ...
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class PostLikeNotification(Notification):
    model = models.ForeignKey(SomePost)

class UserFollowNotification(Notifcation):
    model = models.ForeignKey(Follower)

# ...
```

This has several advantages:

- You keep your relations in your (relational) database.
- You have strong foreign keys to prevent inconsistent data.
- It is "Djangoic": relations in the database, starting with a normalised database, and no early optimisations are `django`'s way of doing things.

And, of course, this has some disadvantages:

- If you need to search **all** notifications for something the query will be complex.
- Moreover, a query over all notifications will be slow, since it filters several tables.

---

#### Use a CharField

You can use a simple `CharField` and store in it the model name and id.  Or two fields one for the name and another for the id.

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    model_type = models.CharField(max_len=48)
    model_id = models.PositiveInteger()
```

Advantages:

- You have a single table, querying is faster if you have the right indexes.
- You can get one of the types of notifications with a simple comparison (index `model_type` for extra speed).

Disadvantages:

- Inconsistent data may appear.
- You will need to add extra code at a higher level to deal with possible inconsistent data.
- Parallel writes (that may need to lock the entire table) may be a problem.

---

#### The middle ground, use several foreign keys

This is just *one way* of implementing a middle ground between the two options below: You add several nullable foreign keys.  Other ways of achieving middle ground exist.

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    model_post = models.ForeignKey(SomePost, null=True, blank=True)
    model_follow = models.ForeignKey(Follower, null=True, blank=True)
```

Advantage:

- Verification of inconsistent data can be made without searching other tables (foreign keys are foreign keys, the database takes care of their consistency).

Disadvantage:

- It has most of the disadvantages of the other two methods but to a lesser extent (at least in most of them).

---

### Conclusion

If you're just starting a project, and you do not know (or are not worried) about the volume of data then **do create several tables**.  Abstract models were created for this purpose.

On the other hand if you have a lot of notifications to be read and filtered (by a lot, I mean millions) then you have good reasons to create a single notification table and process the relations at a higher level.  Note that this incurs locking problems, you shall (almost) never lock notifications if you have a single table.